# how to send POST json from C# to asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

How is it possible to make a POST request to ASP.Net web api from C#.
I have used Newtonsoft dll files to create the json, but, I am not able to send it to the api.

My code is :

```
        Login login = new Login
        {
            userid = username.Text,
            pass = pass.Text
        };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login, Formatting.Indented);
```

How to send this json to web api, and get a response ?

Edit

```
string url = "myurl";


        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            json = json.Replace("\r\n","");
            //json = json.Replace("\",", "\","   + "\"" +"\u002B");
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            pass.Text = result.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I would use [WebClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081760/upload-json-via-webclient). There are tons of examples on StackOverflow how to use it. It's less involved than `HttpWebRequest`

Answer (score 14):

I made it work, by having a few edits. Instead of directly serializing the json object, I used a class, and assigned values to it, and serialized it using JavaScriptSerializer. Thanks for your help Shekhar.

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string loginjson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                userid = username.Text,
                password = pass.Text
            });

            streamWriter.Write(loginjson);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                pass.Text = result.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HttpWebRequest` class to create a request and use `StreamWriter` to write your Json with the request and finally get `HttpWebResponse` from the Web API.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("path/api");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
   streamWriter.Write(json);
   streamWriter.Flush();
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I did this already. But I am not getting success message as false. Please see the edit.

Comment: Success:false was the message I used to get. I made it work. I am posting it as an answer.