# Passing JSON string to php from C#

Tags: c#, php, json

In Android I have used http async client to pass JSON to php, I have searched for C# but have not been successful. Is there any such library or any other method in C# that could allow me to pass JSON string to PHP? 
(I have already created JSON, I just wan't to pass it)

Comment: You want "to pass it". What do you want exactly, send it to an http server (or the reverse) ? Be clear about what expects your PHP side. Otherwise you get no correct answer

Answer (score 0):

[Use the WebClient class in C# to connect to a http server (php). Then upload the JSON string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081760/upload-json-via-webclient) Use Json.net like Emmanuel DURIN said to create and parse json in C#.